# SAML integration with Airflow application

Tags: airflow, saml

I deployed Airflow on AWS eks as a POD now I want to authenticate user with SAML
How can we integrate SAML with Airflow and do the RBAC.

I am new to both Airflow and SAMl.

What are the basics steps I need to follow to start with